# How to Connect a Django Model with ManyToMany Relationship?

Tags: python, django

I am making an app that is pretty much similar to google classroom in django.

I have a Course model and an assignment model, and I want to connect an assignment to the specified course.

These are my models

```py
class Assignment(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(default='no_course_image.jpg', upload_to='course_images')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students_invited = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True)
    assignments = models.ManyToManyField(Assignment, null=True, blank=True)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Course'
        ordering = ['-date_published']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.title, self.owner)
```

But i am getting an error when I specify the course field in the assignment model with the ForeignKey!
Could you please help me with how to connect the assignment to the Course model?
Thank you

Comment: Could you please show the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForeignKey` is used to setup a many to one relationship. As you are trying to setup a `ManyToManyField` it won't work in this situation as you can see in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

```
ForeignKey¶

class ForeignKey(to, on_delete, **options)¶
A many-to-one relationship. Requires two positional arguments: 
the class to which the model is related and the on_delete option.
```

In fact you don't even need to set the relation in the `Assignment` Model as Django will take care of creating a third table linking the two together by their primary keys. You can see this in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```py
from django.db import models

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

So every time you add the assignment to the course like so

```
>>> c1 = Course(title='Python Course')
>>> c1.save()
>>> a1 = Assignment(name='Python Assignment')
>>> a1.save()
>>> c1.assignments.add(a1)
```

And the relation will automatically be created and `c1.assignments.all()` will return all the assignments linked to the course

If you need to go the other way around then you would use `a1.course_set.add(c1)`. When using the model that doesn't have the `ManyToManyField` object tied to it you need to use the `*_set` notation where `*` will be replaced by the model name in lower case. Can read more about Related Objects references in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/)

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I needed! I realized later that I didn't need the foreignkey anymore!

Answer (score 1):

When you try to create the Model `Assignment` with reference to the model `Course`, the `Course` Model has not yet created and vice versa and you will get an error `either of the model is not defined`

1. You can use the quotes for it

> ```
> class Assignment(models.Model):    
>     course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>     date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
> ```

2. You can use a custom through model [enter link description here](https://www.sankalpjonna.com/learn-django/the-right-way-to-use-a-manytomanyfield-in-django)

Comment: Hi, thank's for answering. I learned something new here, that you can put in a string for the ForeignKey. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Course model has to be written before the Assignment model.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem